# Implementing a simple heap allocator with mmap

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I'm implementing my own heap allocator with mmap for my own C codebase. Basically, I implement the hash by allocating some buffer from mmap with the size of the descriptor size + the requested size. And then I save the descriptor of the memory at the beginning of the buffer and return the pointer to the buffer + the descriptor size. I also think that it will be a bit safer if I add some hash for the descriptor so I can verify the buffer on deallocation.

```c
#include "core.h"
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define HEAP_MEMORY_MAGIC_NUMBER 0xDEADBEEF

typedef struct HeapMemoryDescriptor {
    size_t size;
    void *start;
    uint32_t hash;
} HeapMemoryDescriptor;

#define HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE (sizeof(HeapMemoryDescriptor))

void *heap_alloc(size_t n_bytes)
{
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *result = (HeapMemoryDescriptor *)mmap(
                NULL,
                HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE + n_bytes,
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
                -1, 0
            );
    result->size = n_bytes;
    result->start = (void*)(result + 1);
    result->hash = HEAP_MEMORY_MAGIC_NUMBER;
    result->hash = hash_crc32((uint8_t *)result, HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE);
    return result->start;
}

void heap_dealloc(void *ptr)
{
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *descriptor = (HeapMemoryDescriptor *)((size_t)ptr - HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE);
    uint32_t expected_hash = descriptor->hash;
    descriptor->hash = HEAP_MEMORY_MAGIC_NUMBER;
    uint32_t calculated_hash = hash_crc32((uint8_t *)descriptor, HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE);

    if(descriptor->start == ptr && calculated_hash == expected_hash) {
        munmap(descriptor, HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE + descriptor->size);
    }
}
```

```c
// https://web.archive.org/web/20190108202303/http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/crc.c.txt
uint32_t hash_crc32(const uint8_t *bytes, size_t bytes_size)
{
    size_t i, j;
    uint32_t byte, crc, mask;
    i = 0;
    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    for(i = 0; i < bytes_size; ++i) {
        byte = bytes[i];
        crc = crc ^ byte;
        for(j = 8; j > 0; j--) {
            mask = -(crc & 1);
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
        }
    }
    return ~crc;
}
```

Can I consider this safe enough maybe as safe as malloc from stdlib or not?

Comment: There are countless implementations of stdlib, so it's impossible to make that comparison. Widely used implementations **will** have more safety considerations; thread safety might be a concern here. It's up to you and your use-case to determine what's "safe enough". Be more specific - do you have any particular concern?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I also thinking about thread safety but It's not my biggest concern right now. My concern is more likely about the logic of my heap allocator.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts ...

1. Any `malloc` function must return a pointer aligned to the size of the largest *intrinsic* type (i.e. `double` in most cases).
2. So, [for simplicity] the heap descriptor size should be a multiple of `sizeof(double)` (i.e. 8). For good measure, align to 16.
3. Your descriptor is *not* 8 byte aligned (due to `hash`).
4. The `start` member is extraneous. The returned pointer will *always* be `(descriptor + 1)`
5. A trick I've used is that the "magic number" can be a hash of the descriptor address. You *can* hash the entire descriptor but, I've found that if the magic number fails, that's often enough.
6. Often heap descriptors have forward/backward linkage so that a *list* of active descriptors can be traversed by (e.g.) a `heap_check_all` function. The linkages can be `size_t` or `HeapMemoryDescriptor *`
7. Additional cross-checking of `prev` and `next` pointers can be done (e.g. `heapcheck` and `heap_check_all` below).

---

Here is a refactored version. I've *not* compiled or tested it. But, it should give you some ideas:

```
#include "core.h"
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define HEAP_MEMORY_MAGIC_NUMBER 0xDEADBEEF

// must be multiple of 8 bytes to ensure pointer returned by heap_alloc is
// [at least] 8 byte aligned (16 byte preferred)
typedef struct HeapMemoryDescriptor HeapMemoryDescriptor;
struct HeapMemoryDescriptor {
    size_t hash;
    size_t size;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *prev;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *next;
} HeapMemoryDescriptor;

// global list of active/free descriptors
typedef struct HeapList HeapList;
struct HeapList {
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *head;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *tail;
};

HeapList heaplist;

#define HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE (sizeof(HeapMemoryDescriptor))

static size_t
hashof(void *ptr)
{
    size_t hash = (size_t) ptr;

    hash = (~hash * 1103515245) + 12345;

    return addr;
}

static int
hashcheck(HeapMemoryDescriptor *cur)
{
    size_t expected_hash = cur->hash;
    size_t calculated_hash = hashof(cur);

    int bad = (calculated_hash != expected_hash);

    if (bad)
        heapfault("hashcheck: corrupted heap -- ptr=%p cur=%p expected_hash=%16.16zX calculated_hash=%16.16zX\n",
            ptr,cur,expected_hash,calculated_hash);

    return bad;
}

void
heapcheck(HeapMemoryDescriptor *cur,HeapMemoryDescriptor *prev)
{

    if (hashcheck(cur))
        exit(9);

    if (cur->prev != prev)
        heapfault("heapcheck: cur=%p prev=%p cur->prev=%p\n",
            cur,prev,cur->prev);

    if (cur->next != NULL)
        heapcheck(cur->next);
}

void *
heap_alloc(size_t n_bytes)
{
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *result = (HeapMemoryDescriptor *) mmap(NULL,
        HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE + n_bytes,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
        -1, 0);

    result->size = n_bytes;
    result->hash = hashof(result);

    result->prev = NULL;
    result->next = heaplist.head;

    heaplist.head = result;
    if (heaplist.tail == NULL)
        heaplist.tail = result;

    return result + 1;
}

void
heap_dealloc(void *ptr)
{
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *cur = ptr;
    --cur;

    heapcheck(cur);

    HeapMemoryDescriptor *prev = cur->prev;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *next = cur->next;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = next;
    if (next != NULL)
        next->prev = prev;

    if (heaplist.head == cur)
        heaplist.head = next;
    if (heaplist.tail == cur)
        heaplist.tail = prev;

    munmap(cur, HEAP_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE + cur->size);
}

void
heap_check_all(void)
{
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *cur = heaplist.head;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *prev = NULL;
    HeapMemoryDescriptor *next;

    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        hashcheck(cur,prev);

        if (cur->prev != prev)
            heapfault("heapcheck: bad prev pointer -- cur=%p prev=%p cur->prev=%p\n",
                cur,prev,cur->prev);

        do {
            next = cur->next;
            if (next == NULL)
                break;

            hashcheck(next);

            if (next->prev != cur)
                heapfault("heapcheck: bad next/prev pointer -- next=%p next->prev=%p cur=%p\n",
                    next,next->prev,cur);
        } while (0);

        prev = cur;
    }
}
```